# Pod to Pod communication for a NodePort type service in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a statfulset application which has a server running on port 1000 and has 3 replicas.
Now, I want to expose the application so I have used `type: NodePort`.
But, I also want 2 replicas to communicate with each other at the same port.
When I do nslookup in case of NodePort type application it gives only one dns name `<svc_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` (individual pods don't get a dns) and the application is exposed.

When I do `clusterIP: None` I get node specific DNS `<statfulset>.<svc_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` but application is not exposed. But both do not work together.
How can I achieve both, expose the same port for inter replica communication and expose same port externally?

Comment: you cannot expose `clusterIP` externally. it is used only for inner cluster communication

Comment: I want to expose the service externally, not the `clusterIP`

Comment: then, I always suggest reading [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) first...

Answer (score 1):

**LoadBalancer:** Exposes the service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP services, to which the external load balancer will route, are automatically created.